# How to select required columns using group by how to pass query params in nodejs for sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, join

I need to get count and ctin values from below query.I am getting right answer from through query but when I am binding it using nodejs

**Please check my code below:**

```
let matchCdnCntSql="select gpcdn.ctin, count(gpcdn.nt_num) from tableNotes as gpcdn LEFT JOIN tableBooks as pcdn on gpcdn.ref_cd_note_id = pcdn.cd_note_id where gpcdn.org_bp_id=? and gpcdn.fin_period=? and gpcdn.marK_as_delete=false and (pcdn.adm_arch_flag = false or pcdn.adm_arch_flag is null) and gpcdn.doc_cls_id in (?) and (gpcdn.gst_flag='P' or gpcdn.adm_gst_action_flag='P' or pcdn.adm_gst_action_flag='P') and gpcdn.ctin in (?) and gpcdn.return_type = (?) group by gpcdn.ctin";
```

Above is my query statement.For nodejs I am passing query  like

```
var q2=db.prepare(matchCdnCntSql);
    q2.run(bpIdCdn,fPeriodCdn,clsId,ctinr,returnType,(err,rows)=>{
      if(err){
          throw err;
      }

      matchCdnCntRes=rows;
      console.log("matched CDN >>",rows)
  });
```

I need to get ctin and nt_num count as expected answer.Please any one help me ...thanks in advance

Comment: *I am getting right answer from through query but when I am binding it using nodejs* Is the rest of that sentence missing? It just cut out. Are you not getting the same results in your program that you are manually?

Comment: I m getting result in manual case.but I need dynamic query result data.